# How can I omit specific posts from a filter that adds content to single post templates?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following filter in functions.php, which adds some content to the end of blog posts:

```
function single_content_after( $content ) {
    if(is_single() && get_post_type() == 'post') {
        $content .= '<p>Foo</p>';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'single_content_after');
```

I'd like to be able to prevent this content from being added to specific posts. Could I add those page IDs to the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! `is_single()` function accept an array as parameter. So you can do this (not tested):

```
function single_content_after( $content ) {
    if(is_singular('post') && !is_single(array(20, 30, 40))) {
        $content .= '<p>Foo</p>';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'single_content_after');
```

Comment: Thanks! That works nicely. Anyway to extend that to all posts in a category?